# Java Random with seed always starts with same number

Tags: java, random

Edited:

I've tried to search the web for this behaviour but nothing so far, the issue is the following:

when using the following code:

```
    Random r2  = new Random(1);
    
    for(int p = 0; p < 25; p++) {
        r2 = new Random(p);
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            System.out.print(Math.round(r2.nextFloat()*100) + " ");
        }
```

this will always return:

```
73 83 24 61 64 31 55 12 60 78 33 25 39 61 98 
73 10 41 41 21 4 33 66 97 71 1 15 96 16 94 
73 29 90 0 50 85 99 3 86 92 99 45 23 52 7 
73 56 7 81 7 58 77 58 23 85 66 35 81 7 3 
73 91 92 81 92 22 68 28 8 50 2 85 70 80 80 
73 18 9 61 49 94 46 83 45 43 70 75 28 35 76 
73 37 58 21 78 76 11 20 34 64 68 5 54 71 89 
73 64 75 1 35 49 90 74 71 57 35 95 12 25 85 
73 98 60 2 20 13 81 45 56 22 72 45 1 99 63 
73 25 77 82 77 85 59 99 93 14 39 35 59 53 58 
73 45 26 41 6 67 24 37 82 36 37 65 86 89 71 
73 71 43 21 63 40 3 91 19 29 4 55 43 44 67 
73 6 28 22 48 4 94 62 4 93 41 5 33 17 45 
73 33 44 2 5 76 72 16 41 86 8 95 91 72 40 
73 52 94 62 34 58 37 54 30 7 6 25 17 8 54 
73 79 11 42 91 31 16 8 67 0 74 15 75 63 49 
73 53 53 79 51 67 3 45 67 91 57 85 13 87 70 
73 80 70 59 8 40 82 99 4 84 24 75 71 41 66 
73 99 19 19 37 22 47 36 93 6 22 5 97 78 79 
73 26 36 99 94 95 25 91 30 99 89 95 55 32 75 
73 60 21 99 79 58 16 61 16 63 26 45 44 5 52 
73 87 38 79 36 31 95 16 53 56 93 35 2 60 48 
73 6 87 39 65 13 60 53 41 77 91 65 29 96 61 
73 33 4 19 22 86 38 7 78 70 59 55 86 51 57 
73 68 88 20 8 49 29 78 64 35 95 5 76 24 34
```

as you can see, the same number is always almost the same (73 = 0.739...), and if I continue with a longer list, the similar numbers will appear in groups of 10s or 20s, is there any reason this could be happening?

regards,
Jakes

Comment: Because the seed is the base number that is used to generate the rest of the numbers. If you set the seed to a specific number, it will return specific results. This is clearly documented within `Random`'s javadoc

Comment: @Rogue: I think the question is actually about why *similar* seeds produce *similar* first numbers.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Yep, it's not the same as other posted questions, if you saw the results, you will find a repeated pattern in the first number of each seed, which should not happen, as I'm changing between seeds

Answer (score 5):

It seems your question is about `Random` with *similar* seed values returning *similar* first values.

First of: you're hiding a lot of the randomness produced by generatinga 32bit float and then reducing it to roughly 7 bit (you scale it to 0-100 and round it).

Next: `java.util.Random` is not a cryptographically strong RNG. It's "not terrible" in some sense, but far from strong. For example, it only has 48 bit of internal state. By setting a seed you are setting *all of that state*. Since it's not a cryptographically strong RNG it's possible for *similar* seed values to consistently create *similar* output values.

And since your seed values only vary by a couple of bits (you use the values 0 to 24, that's not a lot of bits), you get the result you expect.

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, there's two possible solutions:

1. use a crpytographically strong RNG. Since you *also* want to use fixed seeds, this seems to be unhelpful.
2. use "more random" seeds:

   1. Pick an initial seed (which might be a "cheap" one like `0`
   2. create an inital `Random` instance from that.
   3. use that initial `Random` instance to get the "real" seeds for your other `Random` object using `initalRandom.nextLong()`.

Option #2 is obviously not a real cryptographically strong scheme (not least because it also uses a fixed seed), but if you only want to "hide" the non-randomness of your random numbers then it's probably good enough for casual observers.

Comment: About the question, my main concern is that it will always yield the same initial decimal digits for the first generated number (although this is a lot harder to read). regarding this concern, yes, if I see a bigger sample it will change obviously, but there will be some large sets of 20 seeds that will share some identical numbers, and then will change drastically. And I'm not trying to create a strong cryptography but I was only trying to understand the reason, and if this was a known issue, because, although its PRNG, it should at least not behave like this.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're using the PRNG in a very suboptimal way: you *force* the internal state to be values that only differ in very few bits. A *good* PRNG should still produce wildly different results, even for the first value. But a *good* PRNG is also often slow and requires a lot more internal state than this (keep in mind: if the internal state is smaller than the output, then a single `long` output of a PRNG is enough to predict the next value!). In short: if you want the PRNG to behave well, then use it in a way that allows it to behave well.

Comment: This is weirdly strange, mainly because if I discard the first result, the rest of the sequence will behave very well under any seeded PRGN testing, so, why is this initial output so drastilly outside the remaining results?
So what i understand, the seed affects the results in a direct way, and not in a indexed way, like a formula or operation being made based on the given seed. And its not entirely true, you have a lot of good PRNG out there, without this behaviour that are a lot faster without any weird results

Comment: @Jakes: The algorithms used in `java.util.Random` are specified to be fixed (and have been fixed for a long time). Yes, there are other, potentially better algorithms out there and if you want to use them then switch to an implementation of those (for almost all of them there are implementations that implement the same interface, so the switching should not be too hard). But the consistency of results was deemed more important.

Comment: @Jakes: The specific reasons you see this result are 1) the initial seed is scrambled in a way that provides no diffusion of differences at all, 2) the LCG multiplier *m* is only a 35-bit integer, thus the high order bits of (m+)*m are unchanged for small values of delta, and 3) the high order bits are used for the output of `nextFloat`. These facts plus all the others in this answer are why the very 1st outputs are the same.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: thanks for the analysis, I think that's actually worth posting as a dedicated answer. My answer is focused more on the conceptual high-level reasons. The specific technical details don't really fit too nicely into it. Please post this as your own answer.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that makes a lot more sense now, great answer.

Comment: The list of solutions should include “use the right method for the desired result”, i.e. to get a number in the 0..100 range, you should use `r.nextInt(100)` instead of `Math.round(r.nextFloat()*100)`. Then, you won’t see such a pattern in the results.

Comment: @Holger: that seems like it's worth posting as a separate answer.

Comment: It was worth an answer, if the question was for solutions rather than explanations. So, it’s just worth a comment or addition to an existing answer addressing the question *and* suggesting solutions.